# JBPM6/BPMS catch all signals workflow or rule

Tags: events, signals, drools, jbpm

I know its possible to signal JBPM/BPMS externally to start a work flow.  You use the signal start event, and I have that working fine.

What I'm wondering is what happens to signals that do not have a corresponding signal ref.

I am capturing certain events and sending them to JBPM and I want to have a catch all workflow or rule that if there is no corresponding workflow to start so that these event's can still be processed.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What are you planning to do with the events that hasn't been catch by any process?
Maybe you can define some rules to do a smarter routing of your events. It depends on how complex is your logic to decide what to do.

Comment: I'd like to define some rules to do that.  My problem is that these are external event's.  How do I get them into the engine in order to have rules fire in the first place?